# Display coupon description woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I am trying to display coupon description once the coupon is applied (10%) in cart page.

To display Total I am using $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total

How do I display coupon description?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you have not mentioned where do you want to have coupon description, I have printed it just before **Cart Total**.

If you want to have it on different place, you can modify `action`. You can find it from [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/).

**Code:**

```
    add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'apply_product_on_coupon');
    function apply_product_on_coupon() {
        global $woocommerce;

        if ( ! empty( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons ) ) {
             $my_coupon = $woocommerce->cart->get_coupons() ;
             foreach($my_coupon as $coupon){

                if ( $post = get_post( $coupon->id ) ) {
                        if ( !empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) {
                            echo "<span class='coupon-name'><b>".$coupon->code."</b></span>";
                            echo "<p class='coupon-description'>".$post->post_excerpt."</p>";
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: This works, but everytime there is an ajax refresh, it loads the excerpt... so I am having duplicates... any way to only fire this one time?

Answer (score 1):

This plugin create shortcode to display coupons info. One of them is [coupon_description].

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-coupon-shortcodes/

Comment: This plugin is not Compatible to even `4.0` .

Comment: I have not tried it but it might create problem in future even if it works on latest WP version.

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought to look in the plugin code  to see how it gets the coupon description.

Comment: That would be great if he/she manages to pull out right code :)