# Display coupon description woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I wondered in anyone could help me figure out how to display the coupon description underneath the coupon title in a WooCommerce cart? For example the title is the coupon code (COUPONCODE1234) but it would be useful if underneath or immediately after it displayed how much of a discount this provides i.e. '15% OFF'.

Here's the theme I'm using. You'll need to add a product to the cart to view the cart pane:
http://demo.lollum.com/nantes/shop/shop/

I've tried the solution underneath but it doesn't work :(
[Display coupon description woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017767/display-coupon-description-woocommerce)

Hope someone can help point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using WooCommerce coupon and discount type is "Cart % Discount".

You can use the " **woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html** " filter to display the discount percentage after the coupon code on cart page.

```
function my_test($value, $coupon)
{
    if($coupon->discount_type == 'percent' && !empty($coupon->coupon_amount))
    {
        $amt = "<p>{$coupon->coupon_amount}% OFF</p>";   
    }

    return $value.$amt;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html','my_test',10,2);
```

It will display the discount as shown in an image.

[image: Cart Page]

Comment: Thanks so much!! I was using Product % Discount but I swapped it to Cart % Discount, added your code and it worked....thanks so much, you're a star! :)