# How to check which coupon is applied to which product in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, coupon

Since we can apply different coupons to each product in an order,
Is there any method to know which coupon is applied to which product?
I've used `$order->get_used_coupons()` function but it just returns the used coupon codes only.

Please help with a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> Example made for Woocommerce 2.5.x on June 2016 (Will not work in Woocommerce 3+)

This example is based on compiled searches:

```
function wc_my_order_coupons( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // checking if order has some used coupons
    if( sizeof($order->get_used_coupons()) > 0 ) {
        foreach( $order->get_used_coupons() as $coupon_code ) {

            // Retrieving the coupon ID
            $post_obj = get_page_by_title($coupon_code, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
            $coupon_id = $post_obj->ID;

            // here is a list of most all data that you can use for a coupon
            $cp_discount_type = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'discount_type', true );
            $cp_amount = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', true );
            $cp_indiv_use = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'individual_use', true );
            $cp_products = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'product_ids' ); 
            $cp_excl_products = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids' );
            $cp_usage_limit = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'usage_limit', true );
            $cp_expiry_date = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'expiry_date', true );
            $cp_apply_before_tax = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', true );
            $cp_free_shipping = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'free_shipping', true ); 

            // Getting the products in this order_id
            $items = $order->get_items();
            foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
                $product_name = $item['name'];
                $product_id = $item['product_id'];

                // Example: we use product_ids authorized in the coupon $cp_products
                if (in_array($product_id, $cp_products)) {
                    echo $product_name . 'uses the coupon: ' . $coupon->code . '<br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

References :

- [Class WC_Coupon methods and properties](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html)
- [WC ApiDocs - class WC_Coupon source](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Coupon.html#18)
- [Create a coupon programatically](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/)
- [Send coupons used in an order by email](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/send-coupons-used-in-an-order-by-email/)
- [Display coupon description woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017767/display-coupon-description-woocommerce)

Comment: Thaks for the snippet @LoicTheAztec, really appreciated. Sorry for the delay in response. I've used this code, but there will be an issue if a coupon can be applied to two or more products,am I correct?

Comment: @MûhámmàdYäsårK Yes that could be right. But it could be solved certainly, because anything is possible depending on your time and effort. Thanks for up voting me :) … Is this snippet working or not?

Comment: get_used_coupons() returns an array of coupon codes it's not an object as the above snippet is treating it as.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz It was Woocommerce 2.5 in this time, So it has changed since Woocommerce 3… I Will make an update.

Comment: Version 2.6.13 of WooCommerce returns an array of strings so they must have changed it somewhere between version 2.5 and 2.613.